# Is Angular CLI compatible with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

We are in process of upgrading our Angular JS application to the new Angular (Angular 4) framework. The strategy we have devised is that we first convert Angular JS stuff from javascript to typscript and then convert component by component to the new Angular framework. However, Is there anyway to make Angular CLI work with Angular JS?

Comment: Nope it will only work with Angular 2 +.

Comment: I'd probably try to just convert my app to Angular 4 first, and not worry about the CLI. The CLI is awesome, you should not start a new project w/out it. If you already use webpack to build your app, you might be in a good place to try and use the CLI. For one of my apps, I had an antiquated build system using bower, gulp, browserify, typescript... and it proved very difficult to update everything at once to a newer setup using ngUpgrade ... let alone make it work w/the CLI.

Comment: @SunilD. According your experience with migration from a bower/gulp angularJS app to a newer angular 5+, is it better to switch a build process to webpack first?

Comment: @anastsiacrs it could help. My biggest problem was not having command of webpack.

Comment: Nope.  AngularJS 1.3 has LTS... stay there.  Build a new app from scratch if you want to upgrade.